# why are the following declarations not the same?

Tags: python, tuples

I assumed that I defined a tuple. luckily it worked for a long time.
In one specific point it broke --> figured out that it was actually not a tuple.
In the end I expected a tuple with 1 string inside  like this
`("expected tuple")`

Confusing, please explain

```
if any(key in [tuple("expect tuple"), tuple(("expect tuple"),),("expect tuple")] for key in [(("expect tuple"),)]):
    print("same")
```

Comment: To define a single tuple you need a comma following the first element: mytuple = (one_thing, )

Comment: `tuple` takes an iterable as an argument. `tuple("expect tuple") == ("e", "x", "p", "e", "c", ...)`, because strings are iterable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A tuple with a single element must be written like this:

```
("expected tuple",)
```

Without the `,` it'd be interpreted as a value surrounded by brackets, but not an actual tuple. We don't have this problem for tuples with more than one element, in those cases we don't need the trailing comma.

Comment: ouh dude, using the "," and replacing "any" by "all" showed that they are all tuples. ```if all(key in [("expect tuple",), tuple(("expect tuple",),),("expect tuple",)] for key in [(("expect tuple"),)]):
 print("same")```